# How to use mongodb merge conditionally?

Tags: mongodb, merge, aggregation-framework

How can I use mongodb [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/#pipe._S_merge) conditionally, only if the output document matches a certain condition? For example only if it was created after a certain date?

Comment: there is a field called `on` you can pass your date field in it.

Comment: Simply add a $match stage before your $merge...